# uialertcontroller and user agreement

Tags: swift, xcode, uialertcontroller

I am trying to show a UIAlertController which will display my terms of service. I can not simply paste the terms of service into the message body, what would be the best way to achieve this. I am also only calling it once on apps first launch.

```
  func agree(){

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Terms of Service", message:"", preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Agree", style: .default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction) in
        print("OK")
    }))
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

}


     override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "Walkthrough") {
        print("already shown")
        // Terms have been accepted, proceed as normal
    } else {


        agree()
        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "Walkthrough")
    }

}
```

Comment: I would modally present a view controller with the terms of service as a text view and and an agree/disagree button on the bottom.

Comment: After declaring function `agree` Are you need to simply paste the terms of service into the message body?

Comment: Concur with @Leo. I think you're trying to put 20 pounds of stuff in a 5 pound bag using a `UIAlertController` for a EULA. One-time VC's probably the best/easiest way to go.

Comment: makes sense, do I choose Leo as the answer or how should I proceed on closing this question?